# How to view and merge two microsoft word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, merge

I think this is very rare scenario. I have done merging two source file / text files in the past. But I've to merge two word documents(*.docx) files . Is there any tools(free/opensource) available ?

Comment: Please note you're using Open Office as you said in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which is free. It comes with a bundled plugin that allows you to compare 2 Word or Excel documents. If the plugin isn't fast enough you can try the [xdocdiff](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiffPlugin/en/index.html) plugin; it has support for the **docx** format.

Comment: Cool... Never thought WinMerge can do that with plugin ..

Comment: It's amazing how many "hidden" features the programs we use everyday have :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Microsoft Word to do this.  In Word 2007 just select Compare on the Review ribbon:

[image]

[Here's a Microsoft blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_office_word/archive/2007/08/06/comparing-and-combining-documents.aspx) with a bit more detail about how this works and some more screenshots.

[The feature is also in Word 2003.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100664131033.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the clear solution , But I am using open office, But would like to compare those files from clients :)

Answer (score 0):

use [Doc Merge](http://www.pariahware.com/docmerge.php) .Doc Merge provides the quickest and easiest method for merging Microsoft Word Documents

Comment: Thanks , But it looks like a shareware application. I am looking for free/open source app.

Comment: Most of application for this kind of doc merge will be share ware only.. let see whether we able to find any free ware ;)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word 2007 comes with a feature to [compare and combine](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA102341321033.aspx) Word files

There's also [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html), which isn't freeware but comes with a 30-day trial. Merge cannot compare 2 docx files, but it can compare 2 doc files, or you can copy/paste them in the comparison window

Answer (score 0):

Open Word Documents in which you want to Merge another documents

now Select Insert From menu select "Text from File" from "object" option

Select another document which you want to merge.

Comment: As this is the method recommended here [How to merge multiple Word documents into one? - EeeKB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2665750) it is very limited, compared to the other answers.